# Como actualizo bien laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

He estado intentando actualizar laravel de la versión 7 a la versión 8, pero me da el siguiente error:

Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires laravel/ui 2.1 -> satisfiable by laravel/ui[v2.1.0].
- laravel/ui v2.1.0 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your php version (8.1.2) does not satisfy that requirement.

Este es mi composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2.5|^8.1.2",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
        "laravel/ui": "2.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.3.6",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "files": ["app/helpers.php"]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

No entiendo bien como poder actualizarlo
he intentado seguir varios tutoriales, pero sigo sin entender el por qué no funciona

Comment: Si seguís la guia oficial, vas a ver que dice que versión de laravel/ui tenés que usar https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade#updating-dependencies